# iOS - Bluetooth not auto connecting to previously paired device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio

My iOS devices **do not** auto-connect (auto-pair) to a Bluetooth audio receiver device. However this works as expected on Android and OS X Yosemite. Thus I do not think it is the Bluetooth receiver that needs to be reset. What am I doing wrong? How do I correct this?

I have a little-known bluetooth stereo system receiver: BeeWi bbr100.
http://www.bee-wi.com/bluetooth-stereo-music-receiver-bbr100-beewi,us,4,BBR100-A 1.cfm

Steps on all devices tested are:

1. Turn on Bluetooth
2. Select and pair beewi bbr100 device (never paired until now)
3. Works fine, plays music.
4. Turn off Bluetooth
5. Turn on Bluetooth
6. iOS Does not automatically pair it, says 'not connected'. On Android and MacBook Air, it connects automatically.

Summary of my testing:

- iPad Mini iOS 8.1.2 - No
- iPhone 4S iOS 7.0.5 - No
- Nexus 5 Android Lollipop - Yes
- MacBook Air OS X Yosemite - Yes

I have gone through the Apple troubleshooting guide and already performed the following steps:

- Reset network settings.
- Log out of iCloud.
- Performed a hard reboot.
- Reset the Bluetooth device.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, something I don't understand, or something broken?

Comment: I have noticed that some Bluetooth speakers seem to automatically re-pair with the last device that was connected to it, while others do not. But I'm surprised to hear that this speaker is automatically re-pairing with some devices but not others.

Comment: Just to be clear, the iPad and iPhone are not connected to anything at all like your MacBook or another device?

Comment: You do not use the terms correctly. Pairing and Connecting are different things. Pairing is for *allowing* two devices to talk to in the future. That often involves some process to make sure that someone's not hijacking your device, e.g. by letting you enter a passcode. Connecting is when paired devices actually talk to each other. Your problem is apparently with re-connecting, not with pairing.

Comment: Bluetooth likes to connect to the first device on its list that it can find. Do you keep everything else that can be paired out of range?

Comment: I have the same problem. I use headphones, but I also have Bluetooth in my car. Even without me having my headphones with me my phone won't auto-connect to my car's Bluetooth like it used to. It got broken on iOS 11.3 or 11.4.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with a similar setup.

My headphones wouldn't connect to my iPhone automatically. What I noticed is that my MacBook was actually faster to connect to them that my iPhone whenever I turned them on and both devices were in range. That prevented connecting with headphones.

When I turn them on in isolation with my iPhone, they connect fine.

My Steps:

- Turn on bluetooth on iPhone
- Turn on headphones

Answer (score 3):

Apparently a lot of headset devices can maintain a list of several devices. So did my Skull Candy Ink'd Wireless.

The trick to reset this list, was to **power up the device and hold - and + for a few (5?) seconds** till you hear a strange beep. Then I paired again and the auto-connect worked again.

My guess is that it didn't like to be connected to multiple iPhones and got confused somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my iPhone X I just deleted all the saved phones connected to my car and then it started to auto-connect

Answer (score 0):

I found something that just worked for me - I went into the device management software for my headset and "restored defaults" on it. Powered off/on - and voila! it connected automatically to bluetooth on my iphone7 :) ..hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I did enough research that I've got this one nailed. The big concern the phone vendors have is they don't want to wind up "brokering" complaints about real-time audio latency! Also they don't want to be seen as "heavies" coming in and wiping out the analog wireless mic market. The BIG latency problem on wifi for example is "hidden latency" from retries because unlike recorded media like CDs there is NO "embedded error correction", it's all retries (and it's not delays from bad firmware in the router, I looked into that too). What Apple WILL "tolerate" is transmission over AirPlay (they have a similar mechanism for files called AirDrop) but to use it you're required to connect BOTH wifi and Bluetooth and it's up to iOS to pick the one to use, they "build in" a giant 2 second real-time buffer (read 2 second real-time DELAY) which just means regardless of actual transmission issues the video and audio cross the finish line at the same time, their competition Chromecast is even LONGER (OK for streaming, bad for live). Raw Bluetooth latency isn't so bad but connectivity is an issue. So Apple "addresses" this by only pairing with "passive" Bluetooth devices (and maybe a speaker or two but certainly not a receiver). Android devices will "pair" OK but have you ever seen a Bluetooth mic app for Android, there isn't one! (Although to really get latency down you'd need a Nexus 5X or 6P or Pixel anyway.) There's also issues that between PC, iOS, Android no two of them use Bluetooth stacks from the same vendor which gives "plausible deniability". Wish I had better news, sorry!

Comment: How does any of that relate to the question being asked?

Comment: It's designed NOT TO MAKE THAT CONNECTION for the elaborated list of technical and marketing issues, trying to "fix it" is a fool's errand. So stop trying already!

Answer (score -2):

You could try -

1. Open the Settings app on your iOS device.
2. Scroll down and tap General.
3. Next tap Handoff & Suggested Apps.
4. Turn off Handoff.

This is normally used to allow you to carry on browsing on other Apple devices.

Comment: Could you explain why Handoff would have an effect on Bluetooth ? They're two different things.